# Odd or even hexadecimal number?

Tags: c, binary, hex, converters

I need to calculate if a hexadecimal number is odd or even as a C function. Is there any function to do it directly?

If not, is there a function in C to directly convert from hexadecimal to binary?

Comment: `int i = 0xff; isodd = i % 2 != 0;`

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? Besides, C doesn't have hexadecimal variables. All variables are binary. Literals may be hexadecimal, but being literal you know a priori whether they're odd.

Comment: sorry, I started posting that question, and I realised it was a better question for another forum. But I wanted to ask this too and I forgot to change the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for hexa to binary look at this page [HTOI](http://johnsantic.com/comp/htoi.html)

or you can convert 
for hexa to decimal look at this function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

and then to binary using normal methods.

to find odd or not you can use

```
if(x & 1 == 1)
     //it's odd
else 
    // it's even
```